# Force MSBuild 14.0 in psake build for C# 6.0 code base

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0, psake

I recently updated to Visual Studio 2015 and am using the new C# 6.0 features. In VS, everything builds correctly.

However, I use PSake as build script language, and the build always fails at places where I use  c# 6.0 features. **How can I tell psake to use MSBuild 14.0, so that the new c# 6.0 features build correctly?**

Tried & failed:

- Passing in the framework version to psake: *Unknown .NET Framework version, 4.6*
- Call the vsvars32.bat of VS2015 prior to invoking psake. PSake still uses the old MSBuild version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue & fixed it by configuring PSake build script to use .Net Framework 4.6, simply by adding `Framework "4.6"` in the beginning of the file. You may check this unit test from PSake code base [dotNet4.6_should_pass.ps1](https://github.com/psake/psake/blob/master/specs/dotNet4.6_should_pass.ps1)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the preferred way. Unfortunately it doesn't work on my machine. But I found a workaround, I'll post it as another answer here shortly.

Comment: Or use the -framework parameter when calling psake.ps1

Answer (score 3):

**The solution described by @WahidShalaly seems to be the correct one, so use that.** However, on my machine it still didn't find the correct MSBuild version so here is the workaround that I have in place instead:

Add the following task to your PSake script:

```
Task SetEnvironment {
  Exec { & $env:VS140COMNTOOLS\vsvars32.bat }
}
```

This sets the environment for VS2015 compilation *from within PSake*.

Now add a dependency to `SetEnvironment` from every task that calls MSBuild and use `msBuild.exe` instead of just `msbuild`. Example:

```
Task Compile -Depends SetEnvironment {
  Exec { & "msbuild.exe" "theSolution.sln" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 }
}
```